# chrome crops modal when page was already scrolled

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I have a webpage that has a modal of an image. When I view the local version of the website the modal works fine, when I view it in IE, it works too, but normal chrome (private mode and normal). here are three images to show my problem.

I am asking, is this a browser bug or have I written some weird CSS somewhere.

The webpage is https://www.mickster04.com/mikesrail

How it looks normally (and should look for all) [image: Expected]

Image cropped at the bottom when scrolled [image: Image cropped at the bottom when scrolled]
  local files when scrolled work too [image: local files when scrolled work too]

Comment: Don't just paste a link. Create a [mcve] instead. That said, I'll bet this is an absolutely positioned element inside a relatively positioned element that is scrolled, right? Then it's a known problem with Chrome. See the Related list to the right.

Comment: I have a fixed position div inside a span, I assume that translates to the same thing? In other news, it seems to be resolved, unless the Linux Chrome is different in someway to the windows version. Part of my problem is I wasn't sure what the cause could be, so couldn't be sure how to replicate elsewhere without reating the whole page anyway.